# How to plot count of customer_id in different bins of price using python

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization

[image: Image of DataFrame]

Attaching Image above of the data frame.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code  for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'CUSTOMER_ID':["ID_0", "ID_1", "ID_2", "ID_3","ID_4"],
    'PRICE':[68,53.55,23.78,20.00,48.00]
   
})
df.plot(kind='bar',x='CUSTOMER_ID',y='PRICE')
df.sort_values(by=['PRICE'])
```

[image: Output]

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, but I was wondering if there is a way to make a plot where we can group the number of customers which are falling into a particular bin of the prices.

Comment: You can use sorters :  `df.sort_values(by=['PRICE'])`  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html